# Getting Type error when copying a div tag

Tags: javascript

I use this function to copy my div tag but it shows an error which is

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at clone_box

```js
function clone_box(count) {
  var card_box =
    `<div class="col-4">
           <div class="card" style="border-radius: 10px;">
             <div class="card-body">
               <div class="clearfix">
                 <div class="pull-right">
                   <i class="fa fa-ambulance" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>           
                 </div>
                 <div class="pull-left">
                   <p> Call 108 </p>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>`;

  document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = card_box;
}
window.addEventListener("load", clone_box(4));
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Please fix the format and have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Don't call a function in a place where you need a reference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clone_box(4) is executed where you have the statement because of the brackets (4)

That is when the box does not exist.

You need to change `clone_box(4)` needs to be `function() { clone_box(4) }` and I assume you want to use the count too?

```js
function clone_box(count) {
  var card_box =
    `<div class="col-4">
           <div class="card" style="border-radius: 10px;">
             <div class="card-body">
               <div class="clearfix">
                 <div class="pull-right">
                   <i class="fa fa-ambulance" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>           
                 </div>
                 <div class="pull-left">
                   <p> Call 108 </p>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>`;
  for (let i=0;i<count;i++)  document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += card_box;
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() { clone_box(4) });
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```